# What is the ByteBuddy equivalent of setAccessible(true)?

Tags: byte-buddy

I am calling `MethodCall.invoke` and attempting to invoke an inaccessible method (the method is declared to be package private) on an object.

If I were using reflection, I could do `theMethod.setAccessible(true)` and then access checks would be disabled.

As a hack, I know that `MethodDescription` inherits from [`ByteCodeElement`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.13/net/bytebuddy/description/ByteCodeElement.html) which defines [`isAccessibleTo(TypeDescription)`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.13/net/bytebuddy/description/ByteCodeElement.html#isAccessibleTo-net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription-).  I overrode that to return `true` just to see what would happen.  Unsurprisingly, I get an `IllegalAccessError` at method invocation time.  This also happens if I override [`isVisibleTo(TypeDescription)`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.13/net/bytebuddy/description/ByteCodeElement.html#isVisibleTo-net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription-).

I know that the magic of `setAccessible(true)` is achieved partially by [subclassing `MagicAccessorImpl`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/2d8e74ddea7d2f8495ad713e991a832743aa9d40/src/hotspot/share/runtime/reflection.cpp#L697-L701).  I also know this is in the `jdk.internal.reflect` package which is not exported by default and which cannot be exported if you're using `--release` with `javac`, which I am.

Anyway it occurred to me that ByteBuddy may have some facility for [performing the same kind of unchecked bytecode work that `MethodAccessorGenerator` does](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6bab0f539fba8fb441697846347597b4a0ade428/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/reflect/MethodAccessorGenerator.java#L124).

How can I achieve this with ByteBuddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as you cannot legally express it in Byte Code. I'd also recommend against using the magic accessor as this does no longer work in future Java versions where this is solved using `MethodHandle`s. You can resolve a method handle and invoke it from a generated class.

Comment: Ha; that will be my next question, as I was successfully resolving a method handle and storing it in a `static final` field of a generated class…and then wherever I invoke it I get a `WrongMethodTypeException`, no matter what.